# How to create shopping cart using telegram Api?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

I want to create telegram bot for shopping online.
i use c#. i want to make shopping cart.
in web application we use Session but is there any equivalent telegram api?
or maybe is there better solution?

Comment: show some code for getting answer otherwise no one will consider to search code for you :)

Comment: A little research may help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the equivalent to *web-sessions* in your Telegram-Bot.

From each user interacting with your bot, you will get identifiers for the following:

`message_id`: *uniquely identifies each message sent to your bot*

`user_id`: *uniquely identifies each user entity interacting with your bot*

see here:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message